# SQL query over multiple tables in one database

Tags: sql, vertica

`enter code here`I have the following problem:

I have a bunch of Tables in a Vertica Database say:

```
+------------+
| Tablenames |
+------------+
| a_1        |
| a_2        |
| a_34       |
| b_1        |
| b_4        |
+------------+
```

The tables are not exactly the same but have mostly similar entries. And now I want to make one query over all tables that start with `a_` (a_1 a_2 a_34).

Is there a way to search through all the tables for the string `a_` in their name, output some sort of list and than either use a for loop or join operation with the generated list?

Once I get the new table (lets call it `temp_table`) that has all the table names that start with `a_` I would like to run one query over all of them, something like that (Matlab syntax):

```
for ii=1:length(temp_table)
Data{ii}=SELECT * FROM temp_table(ii) WHERE paste_condition_here
end
```

So `Data` should be a new table that appends the new rows with each iteration.

Comment: You'll need to supply more info here. You can't dynamically select from tables, if that is what you are doing.  You can, however, use a sql script to generate sql that you can later execute.  Show some sample output and maybe what you have already tried to help shed light on this.

Comment: ok, give me some time, I will need to think how to rearrange my question, its not that trivial.

Comment: Not sure i get it ? Is it data from the tables you are looking for of MetaData ?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for the data in the tables that start with 'a_'

Answer (score 2):

@Nirjihar - there is on **information_schema** (you need **v_catalog**), you are confusing with MySQL.

```
   select TABLE_NAME from v_catalog.TABLES where TABLE_NAME like 'a_%';
```

This will return all tables with a criteria of 'a_%'

Just as a complement ! 
In Vertica you won`t have loops ! For this you have to use UDP(user defined procedures), this can be written in the language of your choice (shell,java,R,C++).
i will go ahead and post on model here for you :

**1 - Shell proc - to be created in the procedures folder**

```
    #!/bin/bash
. /home/dbadmin/.profile
/opt/vertica/bin/vsql -U $username -w $password -t -o /tmp/query.sql -c"
SELECT
    ' select * from '
    ||TABLE_SCHEMA
    ||'.'
    ||TABLE_NAME
    ||';'
FROM
 v_catalog.TABLES where TABLE_NAME like '%$1%'
 "
/opt/vertica/bin/vsql -U $username -w $password  -F $'|' -At -o /tmp/query_output.csv -f /tmp/query.sql
```

**2 - change sh file privs**

```
chmod 4750 query_table.sh
```

**3 - make sure you have the .profile file populated accordingly**

```
. /home/dbadmin/.profile
#!/bin/bash

username=dbadmin
password=secrectpasswd
export username
export password
```

**Note:** this is to avoid passwd in text and only have one point of text passwd

**4 - Register the UDP with Vertica Catalog**

```
. /home/dbadmin/.profile
```

admintools -t install_procedure -f /vertica/catalog//procedures/query_table.sh -d  -p $password

**5 -Create the UDP inside the database**

```
    . /home/dbadmin/.profile
/opt/vertica/bin/vsql -U $username -w $password -c "CREATE PROCEDURE dba.query_table(table_name varchar) AS 'query_table.sh' LANGUAGE 'external' USER 'dbadmin';"
```

**6 - execute the proc**

```
select dba.query_table('you possible table name here');
```

**7 - check results**

- a - you will get a file with the query
- b - one file with the exported data(csv '|' delimited).

i have a similar post here:
http://www.aodba.com/create-vertica-schema-fly/

Comment: Ok, this works! It gives me a table with all the tables that have the specified string in it. How should I go from here? Use a for loop or a join opperation?

Comment: Ok, so you wanna query each one of them ? or union the all ?

Comment: @ Up_One I edited my post. I don't know what is better interms of query each one of them or union them all. Whatever is faster/easier to implement.
As for your UDP approach, I have zero experience with that, but I will try and look into it.

Answer (score 0):

To get all the tables that start from a_:-

```
select TABLE_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_NAME like 'a_%'
```

Then you can alias this and join the list or each table as you like.

Comment: This does not work for me. I get the error: "INFORMATION_SCHEMA" does not exist

Comment: Use v_catelog.tables:-

select TABLE_NAME from v_catalog.TABLES where TABLE_NAME like 'a_%';

Comment: @ Nirjhar, yes that worked! But what do I do now, how do I initialize a query over all the tables?

Comment: You will have to use cursor to loop over the result set